# How to model aggregates with one to zero-or-many relationship

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm reading Implementing Domain Driven Design book of Vaughn Vernon. But I soon get into trouble for modeling aggregates in my domain - football matches.

My case is list all matches based on some conditions (filters), for ex:

- list all matches of a league that will take place
- list all matches of a league in a group
- list all matches of a league in knockout stage

As I see a league (ex. World Cup) will have many stages such as group stage or knockout stage.

A stage will have many rounds, ex. Round of 16, Quarter-finals, etc.

A round will have many matches.

However, some leagues **do not have stage**, ex. Premier League. Even 
Friendly International leagues **do not have both stage and round**.

**First solution:**

We will have 4 aggregates:

- League will contain Stages
- Stage will contain Rounds
- Round will contain Matches

For leagues do not have Stage or Round, a special identifier will be created for Stage and Round, ex. NO_STAGE or NO_ROUND

**Second solution:**

League will contain Matches. Stage or Round are just attributes (Value Objects) of Match

**Third solution:**

Create all types of League:

- League have stages, rounds and matches
- League have rounds and matches
- League have only matches

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is, that you are trying to model data instead of behavior. You are creating a relational model (what contains what, one-to-one, one-to-many, etc.), not an object model. Modeling data is meaningless without a context of what functionality it must support.

If you *do* only want a data model, then DDD is irrelevant since that is not a data modelling technique.

I assume you want to build object-oriented software though. In this case, approach the problem by identifying what *functionality* you want from your software, and model that.

For example: schedule matches, prepare/display a calendar of events, simulate progression, etc.

Comment: Thx Robert, you're right. I updated the post with a use case. Could you give me some suggestions? My concern is this league can have stages/rounds but others might have no stages/rounds.